# iphone 3G multitasking?

Tags: iphone, ios4, jailbreak, multitasking

my app works fine in background for iphone 3gs and iphone 4 , if i cracked my iphone 3g in order to support multitasking , whether my app works fine in background mode or not.

Thanks

Kumar

Answer (score 0):

It may, it may not. Remember, the iPhone 3G has half the memory the iPhone 3GS has, while the OS footprint (the memory the OS requires) doesn't change. Therefore, 128 MB on the 3G and 256 MB on the 3GS (512 MB even on the iPhone4), you get about 30 MB of memory for your app to run in on the 3G, about 130 or so on the 3GS, and obviously more on the 4. So long as the memory is available, and you've jailbroken the device to allow backgrounding on the 3g, it should work fine.

How does this relate to SO though?

Comment: any buddy know how to crack the iphone 3g  in  order to support multitasking

Comment: That's off topic here. Stackoverflow is for questions related to development.